C, nginx module compilation multiple definition error
I need to compile this https://github.com/rryqszq4/ngx_ruby as dynamic module, but i received error:
/usr/bin/ld: objs/addon/src/ngx_http_ruby_code.o:/usr/local/src/ngx_ruby-master/src/ngx_http_ruby_module.h:21: multiple definition of `ngx_ruby_request'; objs/addon/src/ngx_http_ruby_module.o:/usr/local/src/ngx_ruby-master/src/ngx_http_                                                                            ruby_module.h:21: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: objs/addon/src/ngx_http_ruby_directive.o:/usr/local/src/ngx_ruby-master/src/ngx_http_ruby_module.h:21: multiple definition of `ngx_ruby_request'; objs/addon/src/ngx_http_ruby_module.o:/usr/local/src/ngx_ruby-master/src/ngx_                                                                            http_ruby_module.h:21: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: objs/addon/src/ngx_http_ruby_handler.o:/usr/local/src/ngx_ruby-master/src/ngx_http_ruby_module.h:21: multiple definition of `ngx_ruby_request'; objs/addon/src/ngx_http_ruby_module.o:/usr/local/src/ngx_ruby-master/src/ngx_ht                                                                            tp_ruby_module.h:21: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: objs/addon/ruby/ruby_ngx.o:/usr/local/src/ngx_ruby-master/src/ruby/../ngx_http_ruby_module.h:21: multiple definition of `ngx_ruby_request'; objs/addon/src/ngx_http_ruby_module.o:/usr/local/src/ngx_ruby-master/src/ngx_http_r                                                                            uby_module.h:21: first defined here

nginx V 1.26.1
ruby V 2.3.8
OS Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
How can i fix this?
I tried made header file like this:
#ifndef NGX_HTTP_RUBY_REQUEST_H
#define NGX_HTTP_RUBY_REQUEST_H

#include <ngx_http.h>

extern ngx_http_request_t *ngx_ruby_request;

#endif

but i'm not strong at C and сouldn't fix it

The definition of ngx_ruby_request is inside the header file src/ngx_http_ruby_module.h which is included in multiple translation units which is why you get multiple definition of 'ngx_ruby_request'. I suggest that you remove ngx_http_request_t *ngx_ruby_request; from src/ngx_http_ruby_module.h and put that line inside src/ngx_http_ruby_code.c instead.
